# Why i cant expand the html?

Tags: reactjs

why can't I expand all the html to fill the entire page? I have tried to do it with `display: flex` and `flex: 1` but there is no way, it ignores me. It is an application made with Create React App.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your index.css file:

```
.App {
  height: 100vh;
}
```